# Excel VBA error when using dynamic ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I am tryin to fill a combobox (dragged onto my worksheet) with the values of a dynamic range.

Normaly 'ThisWorkbook.Names("NAME_OF_RANGE").RefersToRange' works, but it fails on my dynamic range!

I have tried a different solution (see code below), but then the worksheetname is stripped from the reference (and thus the wrong data is being filled)

```
Public Sub FillCombobox(cboComboBox As ComboBox, sRange As String)
'Remember current selected item
Dim sSelectedItem As String
sSelectedItem = cboComboBox.Text

'Empty the combobox
cboComboBox.Clear
cboComboBox.AddItem "---pick one---"

'Get the data from the dynamic range
Dim oListFillRange As Range
'This line will throw an error:
Set oListFillRange = ThisWorkbook.Names(sRange).RefersToRange 'Does not work with a dynamic range!!!
''Set oListFillRange = Range(Application.Evaluate(ThisWorkbook.Names(sRange).RefersTo).Address) 'Works with dynamic ranges on the SAME SHEET (as the sheetname is stripped out!)

'Fill combobox
Dim oRange As Range
For Each oRange In oListFillRange
    cboComboBox.AddItem oRange.Value
Next oRange

'Set previous selected item
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To cboComboBox.ListCount - 1
    If cboComboBox.List(i) = sSelectedItem Then
        cboComboBox.ListIndex = i
        Exit for
    End If
Next i

If cboComboBox.ListIndex = -1 Then cboComboBox.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

So how do I get 'ThisWorkbook.Names("NAME_OF_RANGE").RefersToRange' to work with dynamic ranges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the range by the `Range` property.

```
Set oListFillRange = Sheets("mySheet").Range(sRange) 'where mySheet is the relevant sheet name
```

For some more information, the reason that `RefersToRange` does not work is because there is no range in the formula for dynamic ranges, so the excel properties cannot read the actual range. Therefore, referring to the range directly is the only way to go.

Comment: Your suggestion for adding the sheet name works, Thanks! I rather use the 'global'method, so when I rename the sheet I don't have to worry about updating my VBA-code, but it seems like I have no choice here...

Comment: Yes, now that I think about it, you need the sheet name no matter what. I will edit my answer to be more accurate.

Comment: I'm able to refer to a dynamic range using Name.RefersToRange.  But your answer is more direct.

Comment: @DougGlancy -> how so? It's been a while since I came across this issue, but I remember having the same problem where this approached solved it. I'd love to know another way to do it in case I need it in the future.

Comment: I don't know what else to add.  With code similar to that in the post I can set a range variable to the RefersTo property of a dynamic Name at either the Workbook or Sheet level.  Did you try it just now?

Comment: okay, @DougGlancy. I thought you were saying you had some other type of way to go about it. I will try it out again to see if it works for me.

Comment: @DougGlancy, I would love to upload an example...but how? I don't see an option for an attachment, do you guys have a website where I can upload an example xls?